# Can you keep chicken warm in a crockpot?

Tags: chicken

I'm making a chicken dish that is baked but I want to do most of the cooking the day before the party. Can I pre-bake the chicken and then keep it warm in the crockpot? Should I add some chicken stock to keep it moist?

Comment: That's 'chicken' not kitchen!

Comment: There's an `edit` button right below your question...

Answer (score 2):

I would not do that, it will be overcooked, even if it is just kept "warm" and adding liquid will not help if the chicken is dry.

Do your cooking a day before and put it in the fridge and re-heat the day of the party.